# django-filter - map query parameter to field name

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm using the Django's default user and a REST API endpoint to list users filtered by query parameters. It looks like this:

```
# serializers.py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User

# views.py
class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = User


class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = User
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_class = UserFilter
```

This works good as long as I provide `User`'s field name in query parameter. So, if I want to filter users based on username, I would use `/users/?username=johndoe`. But what if I want to map a query parameter which is not a field in User model? Let's say, I have a query param called `nickname` and I want to use it to filter on `first_name` field?

Using `URLConf` and named group might be a solution but if I do it for 15 fields then it'll be very long.

What's the better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `nickname` to your FilterSet pointing to actual field on the model.

```
# views.py
class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    nickname = django_filters.CharFilter(name='first_name')
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

Comment: The name of the parameter is `field_name` now: use  `django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='first_name')`